# How to call a static function in main.cpp from another source file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a method called **initializeObjects()** in my main.cpp file, and I want to call it from a method in another source file, named **Scene.cpp**. How do I do that?
This is my *main.cpp* file, without the headers:

```
static void initializeObjects();
int main() {
    Scene myScene;
    myScene.render(640,480);
    return 0;
}

void initializeObjects(){
    //Add a plane of gray color
    Scene::shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Plane>(Vector3D(0,1,1), Vector3D(0,0,80), COLOR_GRAY));
    //Add two spheres
    Scene::shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Sphere>(100.0, Vector3D(0,50,0), COLOR_WHITE));
    Scene::shapes.push_back(std::make_shared<Sphere>(60.0,ORIGIN, COLOR_RED));
}
```

Comment: By marking the function `static`, you explicitly tell the compiler that it should **not** be accessible in any other source file. So if you want it thus accessible, drop `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function with storage class specifier `static`, you explicitly say that you want this function to have an internal linkage - this means it should not be visible outside the translation unit where it is defined.

So to be able to call your function from some other translation unit (Scene.cpp), drop `static` specifier, and add declaration of your function to header file, which should be included by this other (Scene.cpp) translation unit.

Comment: Okay, I added a declaration in a separate header file, should I use any other extern keyword? What is the scope of **initializeObjects()** now?

Comment: no need for extern, initializeObjects will have external linkage.